# How to insert Flash without JavaScript in the most compatible but valid way?

Tags: flash, xhtml, rss

I'm looking for a way to embed Flash into a XHTML Transitional page that does not rely on enabled JavaScript, which validates and that works across all major Browsers including IE6.

So far I'm using this solution which seems to work just fine:

http://latrine.dgx.cz/how-to-correctly-insert-a-flash-into-xhtml#toc-final-solution

However, when this method is used in an RSS Feed it seems that Feedburner and Google Reader at least (maybe other feed readers, too) strip the whole object tags and only leave the alternative content.

Any suggestions how to improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Reader only support the embed tag :-/

http://www.google.com/support/reader/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=70664

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use cdata tags in the rss feed: `<XMLnode><![CDATA[ YOURFLASHSTUFF ]]></XMLnode>` ?

Comment: I used encoded entities, but I'll try with CDATA to see if that makes a difference.